# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'aws_xray_sdk'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement this [AWS Lambda Rest API Handler](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.6.0/core/event_handler/api_gateway/#required-resources)  in my lambda code to handle proper response code. For this I needed to repackage the library `aws_lambda_powertools` and add as a layer in lambda function.

All the import related to this lib below are working.

```
from aws_lambda_powertools import Logger, Tracer
from aws_lambda_powertools.event_handler import APIGatewayRestResolver
from aws_lambda_powertools.logging import correlation_paths
from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities.typing import LambdaContext
```

But When I am creating object of above Tracer class below its giving error(Rest two commented object  `logger` and `app` are working fine.

```
tracer = Tracer()
# logger = Logger()
# app = APIGatewayRestResolver()
```

Error I am getting while declaring tracer object is below:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'aws_xray_sdk'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
Function Logs
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
START RequestId: ae8b006b-e7f7-495b-99a0-eb5231c3f81c Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'aws_xray_sdk'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I tried to install `pip install aws_xray_sdk` and repackaged it and re-added to layer still its giving the same error.

Can anyone help me with this? I am new to lambda. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the error by using AWS Arn  `arn:aws:lambda:{region}:017000801446:layer:AWSLambdaPowertoolsPythonV2:18`  instead of using my own custom repackaged library layer.

Reference Link:
https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.6.0/

Answer (score 0):

Tracing (like validation and parsing) requires additional dependencies. They're not included by default in an attempt to keep the resulting package as small as possible.

When packaging with AWS SAM, I'm using this in my `my_code/requirements.txt`, which I then `pip install` in my local virtual env:

```
aws-lambda-powertools[parser, validation, tracer]==2.6.0
```

Additionally, I'm including this in `tests/requirements.txt`, which I also `pip install` locally but which is *not* picked up by SAM (keeping the image small again, and it's not required at runtime anyhow).

```
aws-lambda-powertools[aws-sdk]==2.6.0
pytest==7.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.0 the xray SDK is not included by default, as this would introduce a size overhead even for those who would not be using Tracer.
To solve this problem, just put in your requirements.txt the tracer dependency using aws-lambda-powertools[tracer] or all dependencies using aws-lambda-powertools[all].

Refer This link:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-powertools-python/issues/1872